# Is it best idea to have a table with all column type as "Text"

Tags: mysql, database-design, myisam

I am new to web application developing. I am using **php+mysql**, so just wanted to check that what is best and safe way to create a database schema.
I have a table with 15 columns, the first column is unique id and remaining all are type of "text" and I am planning to put approx 1-20kb data in each column.

So is it good or bad or it should not be like that? So could anyone please help me on the same?

I am using engine type **MYISAM**.

Comment: Like, what where they thinking when they created data types for numbers, dates or small strings?

Comment: I doubt the "best idea" part, but it really depends on the data you are going to store in the cells. Using text (either char or varchar) just because it is easier is definitely not the "best idea".

Comment: Hi Álvaro, I didn't get you. could you please explain in details.

Comment: He meant that the creators of database engines would not have created different data types if the best solution would be storing everything as TEXT. Essentially, no, storing everything as TEXT is a horrid idea. Split what data you can into suitable data types. For example, dates can go in as DATE or TIMESTAMP. Counters or numbers can be saved as INT. Booleans (true/false) can be saved as SMALLINT

Comment: Hi DKasipovicless, Could you please let me know some best which full fills my requirement.

Comment: Thanks shrmnless. for the explaintion:)

Comment: It's probably 'best' not to have 15 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best idea depends on what you're using it for. VARCHAR is faster when the size is reasonable and also that is dependent on hardware and data that you are using. You should almost aways try to store text format messages as TEXT whereas string attributes as VARCHAR.

TEXT columns will not be stored in memory and will have to be read from the disk, which is much slower. Check this [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html)

Also check [Blob Storage in Innodb](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/)

Answer (score 0):

Dedicated data types exist for a reason. Some random things you can't do reliably (or can't do at all) with large blobs of text:

- Maths
- Date calculations
- Proper indexes
- Ensure a bare minimum of data integrity
- Numeric sort

A database is much more than a dumb storage system.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its must to use Text type. But try to use varchar instead od text/mediumtext/longtext etc. as often as its possible.

Usung text will have impact of performance.
Queries on text types are slower.
Data with text types will not be cached in memory.